# ¿Cómo puedo testear mi aplicación sin tener dispositivos?

Tags: android, studio

tengo una app android casi terminada y quisiera subirla a la tienda de Google Play, entiendo que tengo que testearla en la mayor cantidad de dispositivos posibles pero sólo cuento con 3 móviles. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de probarla en varios dispositivos como si fueran físicos para poder subirla a la tienda google play.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Android Studio tienes acceso a una gran colección de dispositivos virtuales (facilmente configurables además) [desde el mismo IDE](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds), sigue ese enlace para ver la documentación oficial de Android al respecto.

Si estás usando un IDE diferente a Android Studio, siempre puedes usar cualquier emulador de Android y pasarle tu .apk compilada desde el IDE que uses. Incluso usando Android Studio se puede utilizar un emulador externo, pero la manera de conectarlo a Android Studio ya cambia.

Answer (score 0):

en android studio puedes crear varios dispositivos virtuales. entonces puedes escoger varios tamaños y diferentes sistemas operativos para verificar si funciona bien en todos.